# su command not responding?

Tags: sles, su

It is bit hard to describe. I will try list them:

BACKGROUND:

1. SUSE enterprise 10 sp3
2. I am using SecureCRT to telnet.
3. There's two user app and oracle.
4. I am not in the server room, I can't reboot locally nor remote since I can't get access to root.

PROBLEM:

1. I can telnet and login as app or oracle, but if I try root, it just hang after I type root and **before** it prompt for passwd.
2. After I login as app(oracle), I can su to oracle(app) successfully. But when I try 'su root', it hang after I type the command **and** passwd.

So there're **two** problems in total. Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: Telnet? Really?

Comment: I don't quite familiar with these remote login thing. I tried ssh on the other server and works fine. but on this server it stop when requesting new channel. So I guess something wrong with the settings and turn to telnet. Telnet works yesterday. Today it just have this root login problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sudo set up, then you could check out what is in root's .bash_profile, .bashrc, and other related startup files. If something is not wonky there, then I would check out your pam stack and see if something is up with that.