# After run sudo and/or su or su - command, the command prompt not loaded, however the switch user is successful

Tags: ubuntu, security, sudo, pam, su

I saw a maybe similar thread but not sure there the issue is the same:
[su command not responding?](https://serverfault.com/questions/342087/su-command-not-responding)

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS baremetal server.
After run sudo and/or su or su - command, the command prompt not loaded, not responding:

```
user@server:~$ sudo su -
<here hang, no command prompt>
```

However the switch user is successful, because when I press ctrl+c I get back the root shell, BUT no aliases loaded at all.

If I do direct root login to the server, I get back the command prompt.
In the logs I don't see any weird things.
Compared to other servers in my environment also no difference.

Wonder how to troubleshoot sudo?
I've tried to comapre with sudo -V, sudo -l with other servers but I think I need to see some debug log what is happening when ran sudo and press enter.

UPDATE:

Some small update, if I run manually the .bashrc at least it loads the aliasses.

Comment: I would try `sudo 'su -' ` because `-` could be interpreted as an argument

Comment: In addition to the above comment from myself, have you tried `su -l` since it's just an alias, for `-` or `--login`, out of the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)

Comment: su -l not doing anything either, the quotes gave me back this:
sudo: su -: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in my environment the history suppose to keep the IP and machine ID of the remote host, but when I do local shell, it cannot lookup for both of them so it was just hang there.